# Change label text for some duration

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I have some text in my label and now I want to change that text for 1 minute and then to go back to old text.

In my constructor I did:

```
ui->lbl->setText("Original text");
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(atTime()));
timer->setInterval(1000);
timer->setSingleShot(false);
timer->start();
```

In my *atTime()* function:

```
...
text="Different text";
QTimer::singleShot(60000, this, SLOT(changeText()));
...
```

and *changeText()* function:

```
void MainWindow::changeText()
{
    ui->lbl->setText(text);
}
```

Using this code I can make my text change at certain time but it stays like that. How can I make for that text to be there for 1 minute and then change again to original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple function like this:

```
void change(QLabel * label, const QString & text, int ms_keep = 60000, int ms_after = 0)
{
    QString originaltext = label->text();
    QTimer::singleShot(ms_after, [=](){
        label->setText(text);
        QTimer::singleShot(ms_keep, [=](){
            label->setText(originaltext);
        });
    });
}
```

In the following example, the temporary text will be set after five seconds and the original text will be restored after ten.

```
ui->lbl->setText("original text");
change(ui->lbl, "temporary text", 10000, 5000);
```

If you want to set the temporary text immediately, omit the last argument (defaults to zero):

```
change(ui->lbl, "temporary text", 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have triggered timer to change to new text, but you didn't restored text value to original, so even if timer timeout will be triggered again, after 60000ms, text stays on "Different text".
In short you need to change text value every time, time-out function is executed, in your case changeText function. For example, some basic solution, which you can improve further:

```
void MainWindow::changeText()
{
    if (text == newValue) // lets say newValue = "Different text"
        text = oldValue;  // lets say oldValue = "Original text"
    else
        text = newValue;
    ui->lbl->setText(text);
}
```

Comment: if I set text ("Original text") in a function where timeout signal is executed (my atTime() function), it shows always the same text, never "Different text".

Comment: @DisplayName you need to interchangeably set value for text

Comment: @DisplayName i've edited answer to make intention obvious